# How to use CreateFromAsset with Room databasebuilder

Tags: android, database, sqlite, retrofit, android-room

I am trying to have this new feature working but I keep getting an empty database. There is not much documentation and the articles on medium are not detailed enough.

Using the `debugImplementation com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6` plugin to look into my database and manually add an entry to it.

After doing so I download the database.

The file itself is not a `*.db` file but I change the name and put the `.db` extension (I have tried both with and without).

I add it to my assets folder and on my databasebuilder I add a `.createFromAsset` with the path so that I can use the database.

When restarting the app (deleting and reinstalling) I find that is it not pre populated.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

This is how I create the database. There is nothing special with it.

```
single(createdAtStart = true) {
    Room.databaseBuilder(
        get(),
        CountryDatabase::class.java,
        "country_database"
    ).createFromAsset("database/country_database.db").build()
}

single(createdAtStart = true) {
    get<CountryDatabase>().countryDao()
}

@Database(entities = [LocalCountryData::class], version = 4)
abstract class CountryDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun countryDao(): CountryDao
}

@Entity(tableName = "countries")
data class LocalCountryData(
    @PrimaryKey
    val country_name: String,
    val country_short_code: String,
    val regions_name: String,
    val regions_short_code: String
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> When restarting the app I find that is it not pre populated.

**createFromAssets** will only be invoked and copy the database from the **database** folder of the **assets** folder if there is no existing database.

Rather than restarting the App, you should either :-

- delete the App's data or
- uninstall the App

and then run the App.

Comment: That is not my issue. What I meant by restart is exactly that.

Nothing happens even after deleting or uninstalling.

I will edit my question to be more explicit.